Boundedness in probability under some rate implies same rate on tail probability
Let's say I have an estimator $\hat{\theta}_n$ for which I know that $|\hat{\theta}_n| = O_p(\frac{1}{\sqrt{n}})$.
Does this imply that for every $\epsilon > 0$, I get that $P(|\hat{\theta}_n| > \epsilon) = O(\frac{1}{\sqrt{n}})$? So I basically want to show the tail probability of this sequence of random variables converges deterministically at the same rate.
One thing I tried was using Markov's inequality which gives
$$
P(|\hat{\theta}_n| > \epsilon) = P(\sqrt{n}|\hat{\theta}_n| > \sqrt{n} \epsilon) \leq \frac{1}{\sqrt{n}\epsilon} E[\sqrt{n}|\hat{\theta}_n|],
$$
where $\sqrt{n}|\hat{\theta}_n| = O_p(1)$. However, the expectation of a random variable that is $O_p(1)$ is not guaranteed to be finite (e.g. absolute value of Cauchy random variable).
Is there another way to show this claim? Or is this claim false? And do I possibly need more assumptions to guarantee that the expectation is finite?
Any help is greatly appreciated!

What does $|\theta_n|= O_p(1/\sqrt{n})$ mean here?  Do you mean that $E[\theta_n] =0$ and $VAR(\theta_n) = O(1/n)$?

I mean that $\sqrt{n} |\theta_n| = O_p(1)$. For a sequence of random variables being $O_p(1)$, I am using the standard Wikipedia definition: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Big_O_in_probability_notation

A Cauchy random variable is not bounded.  Still not certain what you mean.

Thanks for asking! I did not mean to say that a Cauchy r.v. is bounded. I was using the absolute value of a Cauchy as an example of a r.v. that is O_p(1) but does not have finite expectation. This occurs due to the fat tails of the Cauchy distribution. Please let me know if I should clarify anything else.

Did you confuse $O_P$ and $o_P$? Recall that $X_n = O_P(a_n)$ means that $$\limsup_{n\rightarrow\infty}P\left(\left\vert\frac{X_n}{a_n}\right\vert> C\right) = 0$$ for some $C>0$. On the other hand, $X_n = o_P(a_n)$ means that $$\limsup_{n\rightarrow\infty}P\left(\left\vert\frac{X_n}{a_n}\right\vert\geq \varepsilon \right) = 0$$ for every $\varepsilon>0$. Note the difference.

Consider the following sequence of random variables:
$$\sqrt{n}X_n
 =\begin{cases}
2^n \quad &\text{with probability} &\frac{1}{\sqrt[3]{n}}\\
0 \quad &\text{with probability}  &1- \frac{1}{\sqrt[3]{n}}.
\end{cases}
$$
We get that $\sqrt{n} X_n = O_p(1)$. Consider e.g. $\epsilon = \frac{1}{10}$. Let $N$ be such that $\frac{1}{\sqrt[3]{N}} < \frac{1}{10} \implies N > 1000$. Then
$$
P(\sqrt{n}X_n > 2^N) < \epsilon \quad \text{for all } n \geq N.
$$
You can show this for arbitrary $\epsilon >0$ which gives that $\sqrt{n} X_n = O_p(1)$.
Now let's consider $P(X_n > 1)$. For different values of $n$ we find that
\begin{align*}
P(X_n > 1) &= 1 \quad &\text{for } n = 1 \\
&= \sqrt[3]{2} \quad &\text{for } n = 2 \\
&= \sqrt[3]{3} \quad &\text{for } n = 3 \\
&= \sqrt[3]{4} \quad &\text{for } n = 4. 
\end{align*}
Clearly, $P(X_n > 1) = O(\sqrt[3]{n})$ here.
However, $P(X_n > 1) = O(\sqrt{n})$ does not hold in this example. This shows that the under the current assumptions, the claim is false.
